# Smart Contract scam

Tags: scam

So Im pretty sure I got scammed just by reading similar posts lol, if anyone can just help me confirm I did.

paste bin: https://pastebin.com/raw/aLJPrzpR

hash creation: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6e20ecdfa92ccf4325d0b97a54c19fb5de19991c1ee9906ccfa38136e874549a

I read into that the scammer basically shows a bit of profit when the consumer depoists eth to show it "works" hoping the consumer will deposit more eth for a better outcome. obviously I Tested it out with a low amount of eth and well it generated "profits" overnight. so I loaded it with 1 eth and now cannot withdraw. getting the "Gas estimation failed please fund the contract with 2 eth to frontrun"

Not to worried about losing 1 eth, Just want to make sure it is a scam so i can move on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes, this is indeed a scam contract. They usually write a lot of code to try to make it hard to audit and find an issue. So, I didn't look at specific lines as those can be hidden very well and require a lot of time. But in this case we see a lot of code is just a garbage code made for no reason but to make it harder to read.

So yeah, its a scam.